# How to hide a link styled with Foundation's "button" class

Tags: zurb-foundation

When you style a link with the Foundation class "button" as well as class "hide", the button is visible.

What is the convention for hiding Foundation buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in foundation Doc they say:([working fine DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6u3acsae/))

```
 <button class="hide"></button>
```

> Hide an Element: You can add the class .hide to an element to hide it.
>   This will add the property display: none to the element.

if it doesn't work for you you can try this([working fine DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6u3acsae/1/))

```
<button class="hide-for-small-only  hide-for-medium-up"></button>
```

as link ([working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6u3acsae/2/))

```
<a href="" class="hide-for-small-only  hide-for-medium-up button">hide me</a>
```

or

```
<a href="" class="hide-for-small  hide-for-medium-up button hide-for-touch">hide me</a>
```